# How to check for statistical significance of calculated ratios?

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, p-value

I have calculated the ratios for 352 grids in my study area. These ratios can be formulated as:

$$
R = \frac{P(A|B)}{P(A|B')}\
$$

[See data plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CjN1.png)

My question is "How can we check for the statistical significance of these results? How can we identify which grids have reliable results and the obtained values are not by chance.

Using p-values?
I read many contents on the calculation of p-values but unfortunately, I am not yet confident how this parameter should be calculated in my case.

As can be seen below, there are 352 numeric values, most of them are zero.
It is apparent that this data is skewed and sparse. So, calculating p-value based on z-score is not a correct approach.
The main reason is that number of samples may cause biased estimation of population.

What is your suggestion?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Calculated ratios:

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
9.52381
24
24
22.0779
4.34783
4.34783
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
9.52381
24
24
22.0779
1.69492
1.69492
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
3.50877
25.1852
19.209
16.8
4.80769
6.41711
3.0303
36.7347
84.2105
84.2105
0
0
42.1053
42.1053
42.1053
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
21.0526
13.5593
16.0784
9.96016
11.7391
13.0435
37.3333
57.7778
84.2105
0
17.3913
24.6154
55.1724
42.1053
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
20
32.9897
23.0216
16.0784
11.6279
14.0351
18.3824
18.552
25.2809
21.4286
9.73451
14.2857
29.5775
60
52
61.5385
61.5385
0
0
0
0
0
36.3636
76.1905
40.7767
28.3784
25
15.2174
21.1957
16.9565
19.1489
9.03955
10.9453
16.4634
26.2295
81.25
83.3333
61.5385
61.5385
0
0
0
6.06061
5.6338
41.6667
33.3333
33.6
26.5306
22.3881
8.65385
17.3684
14.2157
19.6787
16.2264
19.5312
15.7233
24.6377
83.3333
83.3333
61.5385
61.5385
0
0
0
8.62069
7.04225
18.5185
4.21053
15.9574
15.0235
16.9312
5.94059
18.1818
27.5862
25.8621
20.2532
21.4844
22.7778
21.1009
0
0
100
100
0
0
0
62.5
23.8095
18.5185
4.21053
3.36134
4.16667
6
9.52381
12.5
0
39.6226
24.8175
20.5575
16.2393
17
18
18
100
87.5
0
0
0
25
8.33333
8.33333
5.88235
4.12371
4.6875
2.94118
6.45161
0
0
53.8462
9.16031
14.876
9.80392
11.3636
10.1266
13.8298
23
26.9231
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
33.3333
8.63309
9.95025
6.34518
7.87037
8.74568
9.65309
11.1111
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
17.1642
14.4654
9.5
6.56136
7.64192
8.83838
12.8767
12.9707
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
34.6154
23.3766
14.2105
9.55994
9.30576
9.94398
11.25
13.3829
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
40.9091
23.3766
18.75
20
16.8142
14.4737
13.3829
16.5138

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Do you have any other reason to think z-scores are unsuitable. Your data do not appear to be skewed, and for a sparse dataset, one can first normalize the data and apply 
statistical hypothesis testing as usual.

Comment: Thanks @cpiegore for your reply. I do not understand why my data does not appear to be skewed. It has many 0 values and when I plot PDF of data, these values have much more density making the distribution rightly skewed. Am I wrong? Should I ignore zero values? Also, I did not get your point on normalizing the data first and then applying statistical hypothesis testing as usual. Could you please explain in more details?

Comment: P.S. I have uploaded data plot @cpiegore

Comment: What exactly are you trying to measure with this analysis? Are you trying to detect a detect a difference in the mean, the median, or something else entirely? Looking at your data plot, the data do appear to be highly skewed. With that in mind, you may want to consider using non-parametric tests, which assess the median rather than the mean. In any case, you will need to identify an appropriate null hypothesis along with a significance level before you can proceed further.

Comment: I see that you have a profile on Cross Validated. That site may provide a better fit for your question then math.se, and you should consider asking your question there.